# When I check radio selection then click submit, casue StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Step1: "https://slashdot.org/"
Step2: select one radio button under "Slashdot Poll"
Step3: try to submit the poll vote 
I use the following code to do:

```
public void randomVote(){
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("https://slashdot.org/");
List<WebElement> RadioGroup = driver.findElements((By) By.name("aid"));

for (int i = 0; i < RadioGroup.size(); i++) {

RadioGroup.get(i).isSelected();  

driver.findElement((By) By.className("btn-polls")).submit();
System.out.println("NUM:" + i + "/" + RadioGroup.get(0).isSelected());
    }

  }

}
```

But I got the following errors:
AILED: randomVote
org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
Command duration or timeout: 10.26 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'

Comment: just to confirm your motive is to select a radio button inside the Poll and submit it successfuly

Answer (score 0):

Hi please do it like below

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\rajnish\\Desktop\\chromedriver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://slashdot.org/");

    WebElement pollHeader = driver.findElement(By.id("poll-title"));
    String HeadinIs = pollHeader.findElement(By.tagName("h2")).getText();
    System.out.println(HeadinIs);

    // getting the vote counter count first 
    String votecountBefore = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='pollBooth']/footer/span/strong")).getText();
    System.out.println(votecountBefore);
    // calling polling 
    List<WebElement> allPollItems = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='pollBooth']/label"));
    for(int i=0;i<allPollItems.size();i++){
        System.out.println("POll options : "+ allPollItems.get(i).getText());
        // select one of the option 
        if(allPollItems.get(i).getText().equals("Android")){
            allPollItems.get(i).findElement(By.tagName("input")).click();
        }
    }
    // now submit poll
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='poll-controls']/button")).click();

    // getting the vote counter count after
    String votecounterAfter = driver.findElement(By.className("totalVotes")).getText();
    System.out.println(votecounterAfter);
    String [] myVote = votecounterAfter.split(" ");
    if(!myVote[0].equals(votecountBefore)){
        System.out.println("Counter Incremented");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Counter not incremented");
    }
```

**Please Note** earlier code was working fine but the web application on which you are working (doing voting) vote increment only works for first 3 options for rest vote increment is not working even if you do it manually.

hope this helps you

Comment: One more question, why you used Chrome? any particular reason?

Comment: Tried and looks works but checked the vote number and percentage did not increment after one particular phone execution. the final purpose is to catch the vote results after automation execution. Thanks

Comment: Q1. just chrome by chance if u want you can use any browser answer holds true for ever browser

Comment: Q2.for  that to answer i have to check my self first will revert on this ASAP

Comment: i have update my code as per your requirement its working now but plz note that vote increment count is not working after first 3 options in your application even on when doing manually plz check it at your end